# How to use sklean pipeline to deal with data that read in line by line

Tags: scikit-learn, preprocessing

The problem I'm facing is that my data is too big, i can't load it to a dataframe and then process it. However, I really want to use the sklearn pipeline API, so that I can reuse those subclass operations that I wrote in the future. If I read data line by line, is there any way I can still use sklearn pipeline API?

Comment: Maybe not answering your question, but if you are doing nlp, I have found gensim's support of disk-based corpus reading to really help reduce memory usage and allow big models to be trained on small compute

Answer (score 1):

[Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) can help you out. Basically it uses sparse data to load your dataset so that even datasets much larger than your compute memory can be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn has some [strategies on its website](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning). Mainly, some of their estimators allow incremental learning, meaning that you can feed the data in streaming fashion during training.

To use it with a pipeline, I would refer you to this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931865/using-partial-fit-with-scikit-pipeline). You essentially have to break down the pipeline during training, and then during inference, you can use it as is.